# Mask the first 2 characters in input form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i trying to hide/change (with *) the 1-st and 2-nt characters in input form, but value do not changed.

E.x if in my input form i put `sarahlovecode` in input form show `**rahlovecode`, but when submit get the full value `sarahlovecode`

HTML:
`<input type="text" class="input" name="secret_word" id="secret_word">`

And Js i using is:

```
$.fn.mask = function( regexp, matchGroup, callback ) {
    this.on("blur", function(e){
      $(this).data("value", this.value);
      var result;

      while (result = regexp.exec(this.value)) {
        var matches = result.slice(1);

        if (callback){
          var substitute = callback(matches[0]);
        } else {
          var substitute = Array(matches[matchGroup-1].length + 1).join("*");
        }

        matches[matchGroup-1] = substitute;
        this.value = matches.join("");
      }
    })

    this.on("focus", function(e){
      this.value = $(this).data("value") || "";
    });
  }

  // With Regular expression
  phoneRegexp = new RegExp("(.*?)(.{1})$", "g");
  $("#secret_word").mask(phoneRegexp, 2);
```

ref: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mask-input-fields-without-affecting-validation/37100/15

And it's working but change the value with **, same as input word.

Suggestion to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of the input back when you submit the form. Add a function on the event "onsubmit" of the form:

```
<form onsubmit="fix_asterisk();">

    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="secret_word" id="secret_word">
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in the javascript add the function:

```
<script>
    function fix_asterisk(){
        let input = document.getElementById("secret_word");
        input.value = $(input).data("value");
    }
</script>
```